# Odds to probability transformation

Tags: probability, odds, arithmetic

The odds are defined as $\omega = \frac{\pi}{1-\pi}$, where $\pi$ is the probability of some event. How can it be shown that the back-transformations is given via $\pi = \frac{\omega}{1 + \omega}$?

Comment: It is basic arithmetics, it has nothing to do with probability or statisitics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just do the algebra:
$$w=\frac{\pi}{1-\pi}\rightarrow w(1-\pi)=\pi\rightarrow w=\pi+w\pi\rightarrow \pi=\frac{w}{1+w}$$